# In R with scam package, how to combine 'monotone increasing + convex' with 'monotone increasing' for two variables, in a tensor product?

Tags: r

##### Update:

On re-reading the documentation, I think I now realise that I simply need to swap the order of `A` and `B` in my model specification. I'll leave the post up in case someone more expert than me would like to clarify the situation.

##### Original Post:

I have a variable `y` that I want to predict with two other variables, `A` and `B`.

I've fit a model in R like:

`scam(y ~ s(A, B, bs = 'temicx', k = c(5, 5)), family = gaussian(link = 'log'), data = training_dt)`

As I understand, you can visualise the fitted model like a 'valley', predicting higher values of `y` with increases in `A` and/or `B` owing to the "monotone increasing constraint" and that this increase in `y` will be more severe as `A` and `B` get large owing to the "convexity constraint".

While this behaviour is appropriate for my predictor `A`, I would prefer that `B` only had the "monotone increasing constraint".

Is there a way to accomplish this with `scam`? I can't seem to find it in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scam/scam.pdf)